# Why ModelState is getting false as validation?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

My ModelState is getting false everytime i run the code .This is simply a file upload mvc .net core code. Migration is also perfectly executed. However whenever i try to submit the form after uploading an image the form gets reset. Due to which it failed to get store in the database.
Model code (Image.cs)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileUpload.Models
{
    public class Image
    {
        [Key]
        public int Iid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Iname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile Iimg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FileUpload.Data;
using FileUpload.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace FileUpload.Controllers
{
    public class ImagesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

        public ImagesController(AppDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
        {
            _context = context;
            _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        }

        // GET: Images
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Images.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Images/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var image = await _context.Images
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Iid == id);
            if (image == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(image);
        }

        // GET: Images/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Images/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Image image)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(image.Iimg != null)
                {
                    string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image.Iimg.FileName);
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(image.Iimg.FileName);
                    image.Iname = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + ext;
                    string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/Image/" + fileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await image.Iimg.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }
                _context.Add(image);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(image);
        }

     
}
```

Comment: Also, _you **should not** be using EF entity types as ASP.NET View Models_. An entity-type is intended _only_ for in-memory representation of a business/domain object, which is a distinct concern from view-models (aka form-models). Doing so is how you open yourself up to _overposting vulnerabilities_ (as you're basically letting any user set an arbitrary PK value, which is a privilege escalation vulnerability).

Comment: Add the razor view code also here

Comment: If ModelState.IsValid is false, then have you tried setting a breakpoint and then inspecting the other properties of ModelState?

Comment: Did you populate the form field for Iname?